# Create external information files

Tags: database, filemaker

I'm trying to create a database for property management - meaning that I manage apartment rentals and I'd like to create an exported database (meaning a stand alone program) that can view each apartment by itself. the issue is I would like a separate file for the information which is entered into the fields so that when I update the original file (with new fields and the like) the information that was put in, remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to clone the main file and remove all unwanted records. When the time comes you should be able to import the record back into the main file.